# Who set the If-Modified-Since for request header?

Tags: http-headers, cache-control

For the static content, such as images, CSS, js, etc, the request header If-Modified-Since is set by the web browser or the web server?

Answer (score 3):

Set by the web browser, in the HTTP request.

The web browser will set it to the date that it cached the file, to say "I already have the version of this file from <date>; only send me the file again if it has been modified since then."

Comment: Along these lines, all "request" headers are set by the browser.  Response headers are a different thing entirely.